# Order of hooks error when rendering different components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

React throws the following error when I am trying to render different components

> Warning: React has detected a change in the order of Hooks called by GenericDialog. This will lead to bugs and errors if not fixed.

| Previous render | Next render |
| --- | --- |
| useRef | useRef |
| useState | useState |
| useState | useState |
| useState | useState |
| useState | useState |
| useState | useState |
| useContext | useState |

I do agree this would be inappropriate when I would be rendering the same component each time but with different order of hooks. What I am trying to achieve is render a different component each time so it is quite obvious the order of hooks won't be identical.

I have created this `GenericDialog` component which renders a multistep dialog.

```js
import React, { useRef, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { DialogFooterNavigation } from './DialogFooterNavigation';
import { Dialog } from '../../../../Dialog';
import { Subheader } from '../../../../Subheader';
import { Loading } from '../../../../Loading';

export interface FooterConfiguration {
  onContinue?: () => Promise<boolean | void>;
  isContinueDisabled?: boolean;
  continueLabel?: string;
  isBackHidden?: boolean;
  isCancelHidden?: boolean;
}

export interface HeaderConfiguration {
  subheader?: string;
}
export interface DialogStepProps {
  setHeaderConfiguration: (config: HeaderConfiguration) => void;
  setFooterConfiguration: (config: FooterConfiguration) => void;
}

export type DialogStep = (props: DialogStepProps) => JSX.Element;

interface GenericDialogProps {
  isShown: boolean;
  hideDialog: () => void;
  steps: DialogStep[];
  header: string;
}

export const GenericDialog = ({
  isShown,
  hideDialog,
  steps,
  header,
}: GenericDialogProps) => {
  const buttonRef = useRef(null);
  const [step, setStep] = useState<number>(0);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState<boolean>(false);

  const [headerConfiguration, setHeaderConfiguration] = useState<HeaderConfiguration | undefined>(
    undefined,
  );
  const [footerConfiguration, setFooterConfiguration] = useState<FooterConfiguration | undefined>(
    undefined,
  );
  const [loadingMessage, setLoadingMessage] = useState<string>('');

  const dialogBody = steps[step]({
    setHeaderConfiguration,
    setFooterConfiguration,
  });

  const nextStep = () => {
    if (step < steps.length - 1) {
      setStep(step + 1);
    }
  };

  const prevStep = () => step > 0 && setStep(step -1);

  const isBackPossible = step > 0;
  const onBack = () => (isBackPossible || footerConfiguration?.isBackHidden ? undefined : prevStep);

  const onContinue = async () => {
    setIsLoading(true);

    const result = await footerConfiguration?.onContinue?.call(undefined);
    setIsLoading(false);

    if (result === false) {
      return;
    }

    nextStep();
  };

  return (
    <Dialog isShown={isShown} onHide={hideDialog}>
      <div>
        {header}
        {headerConfiguration?.subheader && (
          <Subheader>{headerConfiguration.subheader}</Subheader>
        )}
      </div>

      {isLoading && loadingMessage ? <Loading msg={loadingMessage} /> : dialogBody}

      {!isLoading && (
        <DialogFooterNavigation
          onBack={isBackPossible ? onBack : undefined}
          onContinue={onContinue}
          isContinueDisabled={footerConfiguration?.isContinueDisabled}
        />
      )}
    </Dialog>
  );
};

const FirstStep = (props: DialogStepProps) => {
  // Here I need useContext
  const { id, name } = useCustomerContext();
  
  useEffect(() => {
    props.setFooterConfiguration({
      isContinueDisabled: !id || !name,
    })
  }, [id, name]);
  
  return (
    <>
      <div>ID: {id}</div>
      <div>Name: {name}</div>
    </>
  );
};

const SecondStep = (props: DialogStepProps) => {
  // Here I don't need useContext but I do need useState
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState({});
  
  useEffect(() => {
    props.setFooterConfiguration({
      isContinueDisabled: !inputValue,
    });
  }, [inputValue]);
  
  return <input value={inputValue} onChange={(event) => setInputValue(event.target.value)} />;
}


const MyDialogExample = () => {
  const [isDialogOpen, setIsDialogOpen] = useState(false);
  
  const steps: DialogStep[] = [
    FirstStep,
    SecondStep,
  ];
  
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => setIsDialogOpen(true)}>Open Dialog</button>
      
      <GenericDialog
        isShown={isDialogOpen}
        hideDialog={() => setIsDialogOpen(false)}
        steps={steps}
        header="Dialog example"
      />
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here:

```js
const dialogBody = steps[step]({
  setHeaderConfiguration,
  setFooterConfiguration,
});
```

Try changing it to something like this:

```js
const DialogBody = steps[step];
```

And then, in your return statement:

```js
{isLoading && loadingMessage ? <Loading msg={loadingMessage} /> : <DialogBody setHeaderConfiguration={setHeaderConfiguration} setFooterConfiguration={setFooterConfiguration} />}
```

Please note that it can be done differently, like:

```js
const DialogBody = steps[step];

const dialogBody = <DialogBody setHeaderConfiguration={setHeaderConfiguration} setFooterConfiguration={setFooterConfiguration} />;
```

And keeping your return statement unaltered.

**Explanation**

Your code isn't entirely wrong though. When working with functional components, there is a subtle difference between an actual component, a hook and a simple function that returns an instantiated component based on some logic. The problem is that you are mixing those three.

You can't manually instantiate a component by calling its corresponding function (just like you can't instantiate a class component by using the `new` operator). Either you use JSX (like `<DialogBody />`) or directly use React inner methods (Like `React.createElement()`). Both alternatives are different from just doing `dialogBody()`. For example, if you see the compiled JSX code you will note that `<DialogBody />` compiles to code that uses `React.createElement()` and the latter returns a real React element instance containing many special properties and methods.

`dialogBody()` would work if its only goal was to return an instantiated element (Using one of the methods above) based on some logic. This implies not using any hook along with some other constraints.

Instead, your `dialogBody` 'function' contains hooks and it acts as a custom hook itself. This is why React complains about hooks execution order. You are executing hooks conditionally.

Comment: Yes, thank you for the explanation! This is exactly what the problem was.

Comment: Do you know how to solve this warning though? I believe it appear once I created this component within component.

Warning: React does not recognize the `setDialogConfiguration` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `setdialogconfiguration` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.

Comment: This approach also created another bug. State within the step is reset each time the component is rerender just like it is recreated not rerendered. I have a validation state within the FirstStep but each time the input changes the state resets.

Comment: @LazioTibijczyk The `setDialogConfiguration` warning is easy to solve, but I can't see that part in your code. It happens because some custom prop is landing on a native DOM element (like `<div setDialogConfiguration={setDialogConfiguration}></div>`) must likely because of a spread operator (like <div {...props}></div>). You have to deconstruct `setDialogConfiguration` like this `const {setDialogConfiguration, ...other} = props;` before spreading like `<div {...other}></div>`.

Comment: @LazioTibijczyk the second issue is a little bit hard to debug, however it is surely not caused by "this approach", but by your original approach. I see that you are doing `value={value}` in your `SecondStep` component. Did your mean `value={inputValue}`?

Comment: Unfortunately I have fixed that earlier but didn't correct the code in the thread.

Comment: It's because I'm trying to update an unmounted component's state... React complains about it when I set the validation state. I'm not sure how to make it re-render rather than re-mount.

Comment: This is caused by the conditional render of the dialogBody: `{isLoading && loadingMessage ? <Loading msg={loadingMessage} /> : dialogBody}`. Trying to think of a way to display the message without re-mounting the dialogBody...

Comment: @LazioTibijczyk like I said, this situation is difficult to debug, especially with an unreproducible code. If you are rendering `dialogBody` conditionally, each time you decide to not render it (when `isLoading && loadingMessage` is true) you are actually un-mounting, thus "resetting" it. The latest complain happens when you try to update the state of an unmounted component. This generally happen because of loose event listeners, callbacks or delayed executions.

Comment: I've quickly [replicated the issue](https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-hopper-1r7xu?file=/src/App.js). Top box without loading, second one with loading. It show error when input doesn't contain letter 'a'. Second is 'valid' no matter the value.

Comment: @LazioTibijczyk what is your intended behavior?

Comment: To be able to render conditionally but with this structure I'm only able to hide the element with CSS otherwise, the component will remount and reset the state. Ideally I'd love to not have to worry about reset of the state. I simply want to type `{isLoading ? <Loading /> : <Step />}` but I'm not sure this is achievable without the reset.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236488/discussion-between-ernesto-stifano-and-laziotibijczyk).